# Listing files recursively

Tags: python, directory

Using Python, how do I get only the name of my current folder and its subfolders?

Comment: Show us your efforts so far. This is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```